# Change default gateway using vbscript by altering last octet of IP

Tags: vbscript, static-ip-address

User is asked to manually input the IP i.e 192.168.0.2
The gateway will then change to 192.168.0.254
The InStrRev() and Left() functions should work just can't quite get it to run.

```
 Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE MACAddress > ''"
    Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        (strQuery)  

    strIPAddress = Array(InputBox("IP address"))
    strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.0") 
    strGateway = Left(strIPAddress, InStrRev(strIPAddress, ".")) & "254"
    strGatewayMetric = Array(1) 

    For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters 
        errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(strIPAddress, strSubnetMask) 
        errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(strGateway, strGatewaymetric) 
        If errEnable = 0 Then 
            WScript.Echo "The IP address has been changed." 
        Else 
            WScript.Echo "The IP address could not be changed." 
        End If 

    next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved my own problem

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE MACAddress > ''"
    Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
        (strQuery)  

strIPAddress = (InputBox("IP address"))
strSubnetMask = Array("255.255.255.0")
strGateway = Left(strIPAddress, InStrRev(strIPAddress, ".")) & "254"
strIPAddress = Array(strIPAddress)
strGateway = Array(strGateway)
strGatewayMetric = Array(1) 

For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters 
    errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(strIPAddress, strSubnetMask) 
    errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(strGateway, strGatewaymetric) 
    If errEnable = 0 Then 
        WScript.Echo "The IP address has been changed." 
    Else 
        WScript.Echo "The IP address could not be changed." 
    End If 

next
```

I found reading the variables before putting them into an array was the key

Answer (score 2):

Use Split() to get an array of octets, and change the last one:

```
>> s = "192.168.0.2"
>> a = Split(s, ".")
>> a(3) = "254"
>> WScript.Echo Join(a, ".")
>>
192.168.0.254
```