# Obtain IP address and change 3rd Octet

Tags: vbscript

I am using the below to obtain an IP address (of NIC called LAN2)

I then need to change the 3rd octet. The below is changing the last (to .15) but I can't modify this to be the 3rd - how would I do this?

```
 Dim HostIPAddress : HostIPAddress = ""
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Dim colAdapters : Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
Dim objAdapter
name = "LAN2"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

deviceQry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter " & _
            "WHERE NetConnectionId = '" & name & "'"
For Each adapter In wmi.ExecQuery(deviceQry)
  addressQry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & _
               "WHERE Index = " & adapter.DeviceId
  For Each config In wmi.ExecQuery(addressQry)
    If Not IsNull(config.IPAddress) Then
      HostIPAddress = Trim(config.IPAddress(0))
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next

strIP = HostIPAddress

wscript.echo HostIPAddress

i = InStrRev(strIP, ".")

strIP = Left(strIP, i) & "15"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx) on "." to get an array, change its 3rd element, use [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0(v=vs.84).aspx) to stringify:

```
>> sIP = "1.2.3.4"
>> aIP = Split(sIP, ".")
>> WScript.Echo Join(aIP, "-")
>> aIP(2) = 254
>> WScript.Echo Join(aIP, ".")
>>
1-2-3-4
1.2.254.4
>>
```

(cf. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104030/603855))