# Obtaining IP and change octet - script looping - why?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which obtains the IP of a secondary NIC, changes the 2nd octet to 30, then takes the new IP, changes the last octet to .254 then applies this settings to the NIC (along with sub etc)

Everything works fine but, if I un-comment the .echo which I was using to check the IP's I can see the script actually runs through twice and then stops - why is that?

```
Dim HostIPAddress : HostIPAddress = ""
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Dim colAdapters : Set colAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select IPAddress from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")
Dim objAdapter
name = "NIC2"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

deviceQry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter " & _
            "WHERE NetConnectionId = '" & name & "'"
For Each adapter In wmi.ExecQuery(deviceQry)
  addressQry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration " & _
               "WHERE Index = " & adapter.DeviceId
  For Each config In wmi.ExecQuery(addressQry)
    If Not IsNull(config.IPAddress) Then
      HostIPAddress = Trim(config.IPAddress(0))
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
Next

sIP = HostIPAddress
aIP = Split(sIP, ".")
' WScript.Echo Join(aIP, "-")
 aIP(1) = 30
' WScript.Echo Join(aIP, ".")

dIP = Join(aIP, ".")
eIP = Split(dIP, ".")
' WScript.Echo Join(eIP, "-")
 eIP(3) = 254
' WScript.Echo Join(eIP, ".")

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
 " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
Else
end if 

Dim strIPAddress
Dim strSubnetMask
Dim strGateway
Dim intGatewayMetric
Dim strDns1
Dim strDns2

strIPAddress = Join(aIP, ".")
strSubnetMask = "255.255.255.0"
strGateway = Join(eIP, ".")
intGatewayMetric = 1
strDns1 = "123.456.789.17 "
strDns2 = "123.456.789.18"

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set address name=""NIC2"" static " & strIPAddress & " " & strSubnetMask & " " & strGateway & " " & intGatewayMetric, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set dns name=""NIC2"" static "& strDns1, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip add dns name=""NIC2"" addr="& strDns2, 0, True
Set objShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You're running it twice, you use `ObjShell.ShellExecute()` to call the script again if you didn't pass any arguments when you first execute the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain IP address and change 3rd Octet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677218/obtain-ip-address-and-change-3rd-octet)